# Map 2 values from interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to map 2 values from Interface:

```
export interface CurrenciesList {
  currency: string;
  country: string;
}
```

I want to map the result like this:

```
this.optionValues["currency"] = value.map(i => ({ id: i.currency, name: i.currency }));
```

But I would like to combine the result like this:

```
this.optionValues["currency"] = value.map(i => ({ id: i.currency, name: i.currency - i.country }));
```

But I get And as result. I would like to get this result into the list:

```
USD - United States
```

What is the proper way to map this: `name: i.currency - i.country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I am using ES6's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), if you are not familiar with this syntax. It can make string concatenation cleaner in some cases.

```
this.optionValues["currency"] = value.map(i => ({ id: i.currency, name: `${i.currency} - ${i.country}` }));
```

Comment: just in case is there any alternative?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Alternatively, you can do this: `this.optionValues["currency"] = value.map(i => ({ id: i.currency, name: i.currency + '-' + i.country }));
`